# how to use ListIterator to print data fields of a node in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I use the listIterator of Arraylist to print the elements of the nodes in the arraylist?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.ListIterator;

    public class ArrayNodeDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<Object> lstObject = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setPersonId(1);
    p1.setPersonName("Tom");
    lstObject.add(p1);

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.setPersonId(2);
    p2.setPersonName("Jerry");
    lstObject.add(p2);
```

This shows the node location. How do we bring out the elements of the   node?

```
    Iterator it = lstObject.listIterator();       
    while(it.hasNext()) {                         
    Object obj = it.next();
    System.out.println(obj);
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: You should cast obj to Person

Comment: Something like `System.out.println(obj.getPersonName())`? etc.

Comment: Can you please close this by selecting a appropriate answer?

Comment: Hi Aaditya, I thought i made the response on Dec 28.. the one suggested by Mr. Evgeniy Strepetov works...

Answer (score 2):

You need to override toString method in your Person class like:

```
public String toString() {
   ...return string representation of person from here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need cast your `obj` to `Person` class

```
Person obj = (Person) it.next();
System.out.println(obj.getPersonId());
```

Comment: This one works.. it works well with ListIterator..tnx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [override the toString method](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) in Person class like;

```
class Person{
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Or any other suitable format
        return "ID:" + this.getPersonId() + " | Name:" + this.getPersonName();
    }
    ...
}
```

Because println internally uses [print](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.Object%29) which is implemented like:

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

Where [String.valueOf()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) is implemented like:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();  // this is where toString() is called over object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the return object of the next() method to object of person or directly receive it as an object of person class like

```
Person obj = it.next();
```

Then either override the toString method of the persons class

```
Person {
..
     public String toString() { 
             ..
             .. 
     }    
}
```

to print it directly using a println statement or create a public method to print the details you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you write  System.out.println(obj) it calls the the implementation of toString() defined in Object class.
Here is the implementation of toString() method of Object class -

```
public String toString() {
   return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());}
```

So, you need to write your own implementation of toString method in your Person class. For example -

```
@Override 
public String toString(){
    return getPersonName();
}
```

Hope this helps.